# Powershell get current time for Asia/Manila

Tags: powershell

I am working with powershell that retrieves timesheet information from a biometric device. One of the search arguments used to query the timesheet is the date and time. Currently, I retrieve the date and time in the local machine where my powershell is installed. My code inside my powershell script for getting the date is:

```
get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
```

However, if someone changes the date and time of the computer, my query gets affected. Is there a way to retrieve the current datestamp for Asia/Manila using powershell? I dont want to use local machine time anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to universal time before formatting it as a string:

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: I am considering also if the CMOS battery of the local machine is not working well, it restarts the date back to the time when the local machine was first manufactured. Will this still work? will it still get the current date and time for Asia/Manila? I am considering all impacts for this situation.

Comment: Once the local machine is powered up and online, it should get its time from an NTP provider and update accordingly.

Comment: The CMOS battery preserves time while the machine is off, but is out of scope otherwise. The critical part is for Windows to know the time zone and the current time at the point the command is executed (whether it has that because it remembered, or it pulled it from NTP, or someone manually set it.

Comment: UTC time is the way to go here, takes a bit more code on your part but doesn't rely on an external NTP server that may or may not be online/accessible, if you want to make sure that the PC running the code has recently updated it's time you could always run `& w32tm /resync /nowait` before doing your work that relies on the local time.  but honestly the number of issues that get caused by changing the actual PC time (rather than timezone) probably means that step is unnecessary unless there is some reason people in your org all have admin access and frequently change the PC's time.

Answer (score 0):

With the script from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Network-NTP-Time-with-07b216ca you can get the time from a ntp server.

download the tool and start it like that:
`.\Get-NtpTime -Server asia.pool.ntp.org | Format-List *`

You can find other ntp pools oh this site http://www.pool.ntp.org/de/